# How to catch events across multiple child Vue components

Tags: vue.js

I am building a form framework in vue. I have components for each field type. Each field type component uses this.$emit to communicate changes with the parent component.

I am able to trigger events in the parent component using v-on directives as follows:

```
<template>
<div v-if="fieldsLoaded">
    <form-select :field="fields.title" v-on:updated="validate" ></form-select>
    <form-input :field="fields.first_name" v-on:updated="validate" ></form-input>
</div>
</template>
```

However, I don't want to have to manually specify that every component should trigger the `validate` method individually.

How can I have the parent component listen for the `updated` emit across all its child components?

**Edit**: I'm looking for something like the below, though $on only catches emits that occur within the same component, rather than its children

```
created: function(){
    this.$on('updated',validate)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> The best way is to use `event bus` or even better in my opinion `vuex`.

For the first case take a look [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

For the second [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)

With `event bus` you can emit an event, and listen to that event whenever you want(at parent,child even in the same component)

Vuex `It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application` and you can have properties in that store,and you can use and manipulate them.

Example with event Bus:

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

export const eventBus = new Vue();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**User Component**

```
<template>
  <button @click="clicked">Click me to create event</button>
</template>
<script>
    import { eventBus } from './main'
    export default {
    name: 'User',
    methods: {
        clicked() {
        eventBus.$emit('customEvent', 'a text to pass')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Admin component**

```
<template>
 <p>The message from event is: {{message}}</p>
</template>
<script>
    import { eventBus } from './main'
    export default {
    name: 'Admin',
    data: () => ({
        message: ''
    })
    created() {
        eventBus.$on('customEvent', dataPassed => {
        this.message = dataPassed
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Take a look to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CSr2vBApSI&list=PL55RiY5tL51pT0DNJraU93FhMzhXxtDAo) tutorial to learn Vuex

Comment: Can you give a hint on how Vuex can be used in such a situation. I know Vuex and use it as a data store, but not able to surmise how it can solve this particular issue

Answer (score -1):

For your case you can use v-model like following:

```
<template>
<div v-if="fieldsLoaded">
    <form-select v-model="fields.title" :validate="validate" ></form-select>
    <form-input v-model="fields.first_name" :validate="validate" ></form-input>
</div>
</template>
```

[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events.

```
<input v-model="something">
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

You can pass a prop : `value` in the child components, and before changing  input field call a function to validate which is also passed as a prop.

```
Vue.component('form-select', {
  props: ['options', 'value', 'onChange', 'validate'],  //Added one more prop
  template: '#your-template',
  mounted: function () {
  },
  methods: {
    change (opt) {
      if (this.validate !== undefined) {
        var isValid = this.validate(this.value)
        if(!isValid) return;
      }
      this.$emit('input', opt)
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: You are referencing this.validate() but would this not require the validate method to be defined within this child component? My intention was that I would keep the validation logic in the parent component so it could be shared between the various child components.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood your point - you are saying that I can pass in the validation method from the parent. I guess that would work, but it doesn't reduce my code any. I've already got it working as in my original example, where I explicitly trigger the validate method in the parent for each field. What I'm aiming for is something generic that catches *all* emissions of validate from its children, without needing to make it explicit field by field.

Comment: @rhoward By my approach you can move show code related to error message etc inside those components. Regarding your point related to reusing the code, you can look at [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad), where you can try to put common functionality and reuse it in components.